# How to download your own and your friends' profile image through FBConnect on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, profile, photo, fbconnect

I'm using the FBConnect library for the iPhone. I successfully log in, retrieve the user account's name, and the list of his friends. However, I haven't yet found a piece of code that shows how to retrieve/download the profile image for the user himself, and his FB friends. Any help or snippet to share?